# How I can sort data by time? data inside a array and object has a inner array where every object has created value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Datas are inside an array and each object in that array has an inner array where every object has createdAt value.

So, my intention is to sort them by createdAt.

In this data I want to **sort** data **transactions** inside value **createdAt**.

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62f4ba7fb45d837c4872a577"),
  balance: 13700,
  createdAt: 2022-08-11T08:14:34.086Z,
  transactions: [
    {
      cash: 10000,
      due: 1600,
      total: 11600,
      balance: 1600,
      type: 'order',
      createdAt: 2022-08-11T15:41:30.729Z,
      _id: new ObjectId("62f4cf0190260cd6310f73b7")
    },
    {
      cash: 20000,
      due: 5000,
      total: 25000,
      balance: 6600,
      type: 'order',
      createdAt: 2022-08-11T15:41:30.729Z,
      _id: new ObjectId("62f4cf5190260cd6310f73c4")
    },
    {
      cash: 200,
      due: 0,
      total: 0,
      balance: 6400,
      type: 'add-cash',
      createdAt: 2022-08-11T16:38:09.561Z,
      _id: new ObjectId("62f4dc2c084c7031e0edc770")
    },
    {
      cash: 200,
      due: 0,
      balance: 13700,
      type: 'order',
      createdAt: 2022-08-11T10:49:18.390Z,
      _id: new ObjectId("62f4df966a3f83c597e20e42")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

I tried this but this is a wrong way -_- 
const account = await Account.findOne({ userId: userId }).sort({ transactions.createdAt: -1 });

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with mongo aggregation like:-

```
collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$transactions' },
    {
    $sort : { 'transactions.createdAt': -1}
   }, 
   {
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        balance: {$first: '$balance'},
        createdAt: {$first: '$createdAt'},
        transactions: {$push: '$transactions'}
     }
   }
  ]);
```

it should work for you.

Comment: I am not familiar with aggregate. So, can you please explain to me where I have to use this? in collection schema or in controller?

Comment: you need to use this in your controller for reference https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html

Comment: If you need to try with mongodb please refer https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/

Comment: [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62f4ba7fb45d837c4872a577"),
    balance: 13200,
    createdAt: 2022-08-11T08:14:34.086Z,
    transactions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]

transactions data are not coming with your solution

Comment: try to console with console.dir to see your complete data.

Comment: same result....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247233/discussion-between-krishn-kumar-modanval-and-soumik-ahammed).